# Translate months to spanish with preg_replace - PHP

Tags: php, preg-replace, preg-match

I want to translate all months to spanish and I am trying It with January. The code is the following:

```
  if(preg_match('/^January\s\d+$/', $month)){
    $pattern = '/^January$/';
    $replace = '/^Enero$/';
    preg_replace($pattern, $replace, $month);
  }
  return $month;
```

It is returning "January", not "Enero". Where is the issue?

Regards

Comment: why regex when there's no pattern really, you do just changing one exact word with another

Comment: You replace with a string, not with a regexp: `$replace = 'Enero';`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're approaching the problem from a slightly wrong angle. A regex is not the right way to convert months to a different language. If you're going to do it with a regex, you'll have to use several `if` statements (or a `switch` construct) to get this done. Using an array seems like the best approach to me.

**How to get the Spanish equivalent for a Gregorian month**

Create an associative array with the English month names as the keys, and their Spanish equivalents as the values. Now to get the Spanish month name, you can simply access the corresponding array value from the defined array:

```
$spanish_months = array(
    'January' => 'enero',
    'February' => 'febrero',
    'March' => 'marzo',
    'April' => 'abril',
    'May' => 'mayo',
    'June' => 'junio',
    'July' => 'julio',
    'August' => 'agosto',
    'September' => 'septiembre',
    'October' => 'octubre',
    'November' => 'noviembre',
    'December' => 'diciembre'
);

$month = 'January';
echo $spanish_months[$month]; // "enero"
```

**Why did the regex solution not work**

The `preg_match` statement will evaluate to `TRUE` only if the string satisifes the format `month_name[space]date`, but the `preg_replace` statement will only replace if the pattern is of the format `month_name` - the formats will *never* be the same. Also, the replacement string should be a string, not a regex pattern.

This might be what you are looking for:

```
$pattern = '/January\s*\d{2}/'; // '^' & '$' not necessary

if(preg_match($pattern, $month)){
    $replace = 'Enero';
    echo preg_replace($pattern, $replace, $month); // "Enero"
}
```

I've improved the regex for matching the date a little bit, but this still allows for a lot of incorrect dates to pass through. If you're just trying to experiment, then this is fine. Otherwise, you should use [`DateTime`](http://php.net/datetime) class for validating dates and times.

Answer (score 2):

The most elegant way is to create an array with the English months and another one with the Spanish ones, and then use str_replace: https://www.php.net/str_replace

Something like this:

```
<?php   

$healthy = array("fruits", "vegetables", "fiber");
$yummy   = array("pizza", "beer", "ice cream");

$newphrase = str_replace($healthy, $yummy, $phrase);

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't anchor at the end:

```
$pattern = '/^January/';
```

The replace is not a regex:

```
$replace = 'Enero';
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$meses_ingles = array("JAN", "FEB", "MAR", "APR", "MAY", "JUN", "JUL", "AUG", "SEP", "OCT", "NOV", "DEC");
$meses_espanol = array("ENE", "FEB", "MAR", "ABR", "MAY", "JUN", "JUL", "AGO", "SEP", "OCT", "NOV", "DIC");
str_ireplace($meses_ingles, $meses_espanol, strval(date('d-M-Y', strtotime($pedidos["creado"]))));
```

enjoy buddy :D